# how to restrict asynchronous call in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code

```js
.state('appSetting', { abstract: true, url: '/appSetting/:appId', templateUrl: appUrl + '/AppSetting/Index', controller: 'AppSettingCtrl' })
.state('appSetting.majorObjectList', { url: '/majorObject', templateUrl: appUrl + '/MajorObject/List', controller: 'MajorObjectsCtrl' })


MajorObjectsCtrl = [
  '$scope', '$state', 'uiGridConstants', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', 'dataFactory', 'cacheKeys', '$window', 'ngDialog', '$filter', function ($scope, $state, uiGridConstants, $stateParams, $rootScope, dataFactory, cacheKeys, $window, ngDialog, $filter) {
      "use strict";
     $scope.loadMajorObjects = function () {
          $scope.getData();
          $scope.objectsList.data = $scope.filterData;
      };
    
    }];


AppSettingCtrl = [
  '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$window', '$sessionStorage', 'dataFactory', 'ngDialog', '$q', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $window, $sessionStorage, dataFactory, ngDialog, $q) {
      "use strict";
    $scope.getData = function () {

          var appId = $scope.currentAppId;
          var type = $scope.majorObject.type;
          if (_.isEmpty(appId)) {
              return;
          }
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          //   var cacheKey = { key: cacheKeys.objectTypeList($scope.asCacheOptions({ ObjectType: type })) };
          dataFactory.get("/MajorObject/All?applicationId=" + $scope.currentAppId + "&type=" + type)
                 .then(function (result) {
                     $scope.selectAppSetting('Major Objects');
                     $scope.filterData = result.data.data;
                     deferred.resolve($scope.filterData);
                     
                 });
                 return deferred.promise;
      };
    }];
```

```html
 <div ng-controller="AppSettingCtrl" class="row appReady">
            @RenderPage("_TopNavBar.cshtml")
            <button id="myCheck" ng-click="showSearchPopUp()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"> <span>Search</span> </i> </button>
        </div>
```

In the above code call `getData()` from `majorObjectCtrl`. After the controll goes to `appSettingCtrl` `getData()` function then immediately transfer to `majorObjectCtrl`, next load data from services in `appSettingCtrl`. But after load data from services i want to transfer to `majorObjectCtrl`

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning the promise from `getData`. Then in `loadMajorObjects`, you can chain it with `.then` to utilize the `$scope.filterData`.

Here is an improvement of `getData`.

```
$scope.getData = function () {
      var appId = $scope.currentAppId;
      var type = $scope.majorObject.type;
      if (_.isEmpty(appId)) {
          return $q.when();
      }
      //   var cacheKey = { key: cacheKeys.objectTypeList($scope.asCacheOptions({ ObjectType: type })) };
      dataFactory.get("/MajorObject/All?applicationId=" + $scope.currentAppId + "&type=" + type)
             .then(function (result) {
                 $scope.selectAppSetting('Major Objects');
                 return result.data.data;
             });
  };
```

and `loadMajorObjects`:

```
  $scope.loadMajorObjects = function () {
      $scope.getData().then(function(filterData) {
           $scope.objectsList.data = filterData;
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.loadMajorObjects = function () {
    $scope.getData().then(function (result) {
        $scope.objectsList.data = result;
    });
};
```